# Getting next alarm information when there is no such function

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, alarm

I have this code in my app

```
Alarm1 = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
```

Its working on htcs,motorolas,but  not on galaxy s phones.The application crashes.
Would the following  catch the error without crashing the application service?

```
 String Alarm1=null;
 try{
     Alarm1 = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
     Log.i("Exception", "Exception next alarm not found = " + e);
     }
   if (TextUtils.isEmpty(Alarm1)) {
      //if i am i here either no alarm is set or couldn't read it from the phone
      //do something else
    }
```

Unless there is a different code for the galaxy s, and can i find it.How can i make it throw an exception on a phone that works, for testing purposes?Thanks.

Comment: If you have a Galaxy S, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your exception. If you have already shipped your app, and these are reports coming in from users, you hopefully have something that will report the stack traces to you (e.g., Flurry, DroidDrop). Once we have a stack trace to examine, we can give you better advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on a widget i developed, it seems that on Galaxy S there is no entry on settings.db with ID NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, this makes the app crash. Sadly using try/catch it's not enough to solve the issue, widget still crashes.

I don't have a Galaxy S to debug the issue, if you find any workaround (other than inserting using sqlite3 the row con settings.db) let me know. Maybe you can try to simulate this behaviour by passing an invalid ID to the Settings function, i will try later today...

P.S. To temporary fix this on galaxy s you can (via adb shell)

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
UPDATE "system" SET value='' WHERE name='next_alarm_formatted';
```

Answer (score 0):

Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED is deprecated since API 21. Use the following instead:

```
AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmInfo = am.getNextAlarmClock();
```

where am is an instance of AlarmManager.